# Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render when trying to have a nested loop

Tags: reactjs

I know same question probably asked multiple times. But I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

This is the code for Task:

```
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import "./Idea.css";
import GetData from '../restApiMethods/GetData';
import React from "react";

function Task() {
    const ids = GetData("ideas/id");
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="idea-design">   
                <div className="container">
                    {
                        ids.map((id,index) => {
                            return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                {
                                GetData(`ideas/${id}`).map((task,index) => {
                                    return(
                                        <div key={index} className="row border border-secondary">
                                            <div className="col">
                                                <div> 
                                                    <p>{task.taskDescription}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                                }
                            </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      )
}

export default Task
```

**Getdata dunction:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {useState, useEffect}  from "react";

function GetData(data) {

    const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{ 
    const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/${data}`).then(res =>{
    console.log(res);
    setDatas(res.data);
        });
    };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
      
    return datas;
}

export default GetData
```

If someone can give me some idea why I'm getting this error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render, would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetData` actually is a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) because it's a function that calls hooks. Therefore [subject to the rules of hooks.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

It should be called `useGetData` -- I'll refer to it as that for this answer. You can't call it in a loop, as when the `ids` array changes length, the number of calls to `useGetData` will change in the parent component `Task`. This isn't allowed in React because hooks are supposed to be in a predictable order and never change -- it's a declarative model.

To fix this, break out a new component called `Task` (rename your current one to `Tasks` or whatever makes sense for you) and call it once in there. This doesn't break the rules of hooks as it is only *within a component* that the number of calls can't change between renders.

Tasks

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import "./Idea.css";
import useGetData from "../restApiMethods/useGetData";
import React from "react";

import Task from "./Task";

function Tasks() {
  const ids = useGetData("ideas/id");
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="idea-design">
        <div className="container">
          {ids.map((id, index) => {
            return <Task id={id} key={id} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tasks;
```

Task

```
export default function Task({ id }) {
  const data = useGetData(`ideas/${id}`);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((task, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} className="row border border-secondary">
            <div className="col">
              <div>
                <p>{task.taskDescription}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useGetData(data) {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/${data}`).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setDatas(res.data);
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return data;
}

export default useGetData;
```

Comment: BTW I fixed it one but the `key={index}` in `Task` is bad. You shouldn't use index for keys, it should be the id. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys. If there is an ID property on  `task` in `{data.map((task, index) => {` you should use that